# Java Servlet RequestDispatcher didn't forward the url

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

I have problem with RequestDispatcher in Java Servlet, it didn't forward to the specific url if the servlet path is not in root path

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userPath=request.getServletPath();
    String view = null;

    if(userPath.equals("/admin")) //it's okay, forwarded
    {
            view="admin";
    }
    else if(userPath.equals("/admin/tambahArtikel")) //it's not forwarded
    {
        view="tambahArtikel";
    }
    else if(userPath.equals("/kategori")) //it's okay, forwarded
    {
        view="kategori";
    }
    String url="WEB-INF/view/"+ view +".jsp";

   request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}
```

and this is my web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.agung.webhakakses.servlet.ServletController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/tambahArtikel</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/kategori</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

i think the problem is in the path but i'm not sure

Comment: what happens when you try this?

Comment: when i try http://localhost:8080/WebHakAkses/admin it's delivered the page i want, but http://localhost:8080/WebHakAkses/admin/tambahArtikel gives me 404 error says "http://localhost:8080/WebHakAkses/admin/tambahArtikel"
what i mean root is http://localhost:8080/WebHakAkses/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29):

> The pathname specified may be relative, although it cannot extend
>   outside the current servlet context. If the path begins with a "/" it
>   is interpreted as relative to the current context root. This method
>   returns null if the servlet container cannot return a
>   RequestDispatcher.

In your code, you build the url this way:

```
String url="WEB-INF/view/"+ view +".jsp";
```

So, as the javadoc also says:

> The difference between this method and
>   ServletContext#getRequestDispatcher is that this method can take a
>   relative path.

So if your request URI is `"/admin/tambahArtikel"` and your forwarding URI does not start with a `"/"` then it will be relative, so the forward is sended to `"/admin/" + "WEB-INF/view/"+ view +".jsp"`

If you need to forward to a resource in the `WEB-INF` directory start your URI with a "/" so the path will be relative to the context root.