# JSP returns HTTP Status 404 - Not Found glassfish

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, glassfish

I build java web application,and I try to login with cookies... So I insert user and password values, user is gerardo password 12345.. When I insert it, JSP respond my request but I get an issue...anyone can help me? I upload code here:

https://mega.nz/#F!s0V2WaZb!Q5zoZFm11VP2IJ_lc6Wolw

Note**: Im using NETBEANS IDE and GLASSFISH server

Comment: are you getting the issue when you are redirecting to index,html or redirecting to Procesardatos.jsp?

Comment: its supposed it redirect to index.html because in my jsp I have response.sendRedirect("Index.html");  but I received status 404

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216145/java-servlet-requestdispatcher-didnt-forward-the-url

Comment: As I can see, I need to add url mapping to redirect to my servlet? I'm a little confused

Comment: give complete path Or make sure that index.html is present in same directory as of your Login Servlet

Comment: If i put index.html in same direcory as login servlet I have an issue because login servlet are in source packages of my app

Comment: Give full path of index.html like http://<domain_name>/<direcorry>/index.html

Comment: ooooh.. I solved it... my Issue is because my jsp file are inside WEB-INF folder... so when Index.html try to call it.. it returns error, because not in the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give full path of index.html like http://domain_name/direcorry/index.html as index.html may not be present in same location of jsp file.

Comment: I do it... and I want to know how can I add cookies counter to my app.. for example... I login... counter now is 1... if I refresh my web page counter = 2 , I need to make new question for it?